# Meteor 1.5 dynamic imports with offline support

Tags: javascript, meteor, dynamic-import

I'm using Meteor 1.5, FlowRouter and Blaze.

I've been working on an app which requires offline support, unfortunately it also has several (large) areas of the app that are only available to a small subset of users, to avoid bloating the initial JS download with content most users won't require, I'm using dynamic imports at the `FlowRouter.route({action})` level.

For offline mode (in addition to handling the data, etc) I'm using a service worker to cache the JS, CSS and HTML. Unfortunately, because dynamic imports work over the websocket, it isn't possible to cache these as they are loaded.

Fortunately, the user has to notify the server of their intent to work offline (so relevant data and files, videos, etc can be downloaded), this gives the opportunity to load these dynamic imports prior to the client going offline.

What are my options for caching dynamic imports? What I've considered so far:

1. writing a simple package with all the dynamic imports loaded statically, and with `{lazy: true}` defined in the `package.js`.

   - requires quite a lot of restructuring
   - the `lazy: true` means the package isn't actually available via a URL, it seems it is only available as a dynamic import itself.
2. writing a server side "fetcher" that will take a package name as an argument and serve the content from the file system

   - I don't know how the client side packages are stored on the server, and if the server has access to those files at all.
3. using browserify (or something similar) to manually generate a static js bundle in `/public` which can be downloaded when the client states their intent to go offline

   - Its very manual, and a change to the dynamic imports could easily be missed.

Has anyone attempted this before, I know meteor doesn't officially support service workers, but as far as I can tell, with the exception of dynamic imports, it plays nice with them

Comment: My understanding is that dynamic imports caches all dynamically imported modules by default using IndexedDB. Does the current implementation not serve your needs? See https://blog.meteor.com/dynamic-imports-in-meteor-1-5-c6130419c3cd "all of the modules are cached individually on the client so that next time they can be loaded from persistent storage"

Comment: @kooc, the problem has two parts, the first I resolved: dynamic import caching is disabled during development, I downloaded the dynamic-import package and enabled it for testing, but you have to be careful, it doesn't always display the latest version, which is probably why its disabled. The second part is mostly how to ensure that when a user goes offline, they fetch all the dynamic imports they don't already have - this is what I'm currently working on, though the only way I've found is to just list them all in a single file, which I then dynamically import when the user enables offline mode